# Extract specific variable names from functions

Tags: python

Below you can see the function for extracting separate words from the text. Below you can see the text and code.

```
import re

text = '''

def function_cal(revenues_shops, surplus_margin, meadian_profit):
     median_profit= revenues_shops* surplus_margin
     return median_profit
 
def function_cal_new (revenues_stories_new, surplus_margin_new, meadian_profit):
     median_profit= revenues_stories_new* surplus_margin_new
     return median_profit   
 
def function_cal_new1 (revenues_stories_new1, surplus_margin_new1, meadian_profit):
     median_profit= revenues_stories_new1* surplus_margin_new1
     return median_profit      
    
'''
    
def extraction_variables(text):
    splited_table1, splited_table2 = dict(), dict()
    lines = text.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
            x = re.search(r"^def.*:$", line)
            if x is not None:
                values = x[0].split('def ')[1].split('(')
                splited_table1 = values[0]
                splited_table2 = values[1][:-2].split(', ')
                yield splited_table1, splited_table2

splited_table1, splited_table2 = zip(*extraction_variables(text))
```

Now I want to put extracted words from splited_table1 and splited_table2 in the same place.

I tried with next line of code:

```
splited_table1+splited_table2
```

But after execution of the above line I have results this results:

```
('function_cal',
 'function_cal_new ',
 'function_cal_new1 ',
 ['revenues_shops', 'surplus_margin', 'meadian_profit'],
 ['revenues_stories_new', 'surplus_margin_new', 'meadian_profit'],
 ['revenues_stories_new1', 'surplus_margin_new1', 'meadian_profit'])
```

But instead of having only words separated by commas, I can see a lot of brackets. So can anybody help me how to solve this and to have only words without brackets and quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place the words into a data structure you can use the following code (replacing the last line of code in you shared):

```
splited_table1, splited_table2 = zip(*extraction_variables(text))
table = []
for elem in splited_table1:
    table.append(elem)
for sub_array in splited_table2:
    for elem in sub_array:
        table.append(elem)
print(table)
```

The complete code looks like this:

```
import re

text = '''

def function_cal(revenues_shops, surplus_margin, meadian_profit):
     median_profit= revenues_shops* surplus_margin
     return median_profit

def function_cal_new (revenues_stories_new, surplus_margin_new, meadian_profit):
     median_profit= revenues_stories_new* surplus_margin_new
     return median_profit   

def function_cal_new1 (revenues_stories_new1, surplus_margin_new1, meadian_profit):
     median_profit= revenues_stories_new1* surplus_margin_new1
     return median_profit      

'''


def extraction_variables(text):
    splited_table1, splited_table2 = dict(), dict()
    lines = text.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        x = re.search(r"^def.*:$", line)
        if x is not None:
            values = x[0].split('def ')[1].split('(')
            splited_table1 = values[0]
            splited_table2 = values[1][:-2].split(', ')
            yield splited_table1, splited_table2


splited_table1, splited_table2 = zip(*extraction_variables(text))
table = []
for elem in splited_table1:
    table.append(elem)
for sub_array in splited_table2:
    for elem in sub_array:
        table.append(elem)
print(table)
```

And the output looks like this:

```
['function_cal', 'function_cal_new ', 'function_cal_new1 ', 'revenues_shops', 'surplus_margin', 'meadian_profit', 'revenues_stories_new', 'surplus_margin_new', 'meadian_profit', 'revenues_stories_new1', 'surplus_margin_new1', 'meadian_profit']
```

It won't be without brackets or quotes because they represent a list, and the quotes represent the strings. If you iterate through the list and print the elements, there won't be quotes around the strings.